# Where vim searches for its filename completion ctrl-x ctrl-f?

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I have a bunch of files in (project)/src and (project)/inc.

When I press `<C-x><C-f>` vim should give me suggestions about filenames from there but I couldn't find how to set the directories it searches in.

The documentation I read says only that `<C-p>` and `<C-n>` moves inside the list but nothing about calibrating the search path.

Comment: I think it's just the current directory. The help suggests that it could in future use 'path', but doesn't currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its the `pwd` or the path from where the `vim` was launched.Its not configurable.

Although a new feature called `path`-support will be available in `vim` soon:
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27path%27

That might help you configure more.

In the meantime try these vim plugins:

FuzzyFinder
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script%5Fid=1984

zvim
https://bitbucket.org/ZyX_I/zvim

t-command
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3025

Or you can write your own vim plugin.

Refer:
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Searching_for_files_in_a_directory_listing
And
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Source_vimrc_and_use_tags_in_a_parent_directory

Comment: No, the question is about Vim's insert-mode filename completion, invoked using `<c-x><c-f>`.

Answer (score 5):

```
set autochdir
```

automatically sets the "current directory" to the one containing the current file. Put it in your vimrc, enjoy life.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've done to solve the problem, seems much more easier than @askmish solution.
Edit `vimrc` and add this mapping :

```
map <F4> :cd %:h<CR>
```

from now on, press `F4` to switch to current directory.
Now when you press `<C-X><C-F>` you can see a list of all files in your current working directory.